# Why won't the else statement run?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a function that checks to see if all elements in an array are equal, but for some reason, the else statement never seems to run, even when the if condition IS NOT TRUE. Any reason for this weird behavior? I actually displayed the result of the boolean expression `a(i) = a(i + 1)` and it was false. What could be going on here?

VB.NET Code:

```
Function EqualItems(ByVal a As Integer())
    For i As Integer = 1 To a.Length - 1
        If a(i) = a(i + 1) Then
            If i + 1 = a.Length Then
                Return True
            End If
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: What does the debugger show you when you step through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than a few things wrong here, I will explain in a bit...

First here's what I would do using `Linq`. Just make sure to `Import System.Linq` at the top of your class file...

```
Public Function IsEqual(ByVal a As Integer()) As Boolean
    Return a IsNot Nothing AndAlso a.count > 0 AndAlso a.Distinct.Count() = 1                   
End Function
```

**Breakdown of function**

- Make sure the array is not nothing.
- We have more than one item so we can compare the other's in the array.
- Finally do the compare of the items. The `.Distinct.Count() = 1` will return a boolean of either True or False compare to all items that are in the array...

**Note: Not good for comparing some objects this way...**

**Your Issue's**

1. The first problem is this: `For i As Integer = 1 To a.Length - 1`. Should start at `0` for arrays. So it should look like this: `For i As Integer = 0 To a.Length - 1`.
2. The next is: `If a(i) = a(i + 1) Then`. This is where you would throw the `IndexOutOfRange` exception as because there might be not index at: `a(i + 1)`. Solution: `If Not (i + 1 = a.Length) Then` check before trying to access that index...
3. You can declare a `Boolean` variable to False before everything. Then if anywhere the items are not equal return false or set the boolean to false and return that...

**On a side note**

Implement some `Try Catch` blocks to catch and handle the errors. Turn `Option Strict On`... If you had this on it would say something about the function may not return anything (cant remember what exactly that message is off-hand).

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, what is Linq? I have been using VB.NET for school for about 3-4 months now, so I am not familiar with the rest of .NET yet.

Comment: It has [powerful query capabilites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx). Known as **Language-Integrated Query**

Comment: Not only the function I provided to you return what you actually needed, but it also checks to see if anything is there and we have more than one item to compare in one statement :)

Comment: That is awesome! Can Linq be used at all to search multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Linq is powerful and can do many things, some frown upon the usage of it. There's some pro's and con's, but I have used it many times in projects and work's well.